# AngularJS - Linking script into body tag

Tags: angularjs

Here is my current Body tag:

```
<body ng-app="Mood">

<div id="moodApp" ng-view></div>

<script src="js/angular.js"></script>
<script src="js/angular-route-min.js"></script>
<script src="js/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.2.1/Chart.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/main.js"></script>
```

And here is the files tree :

[image]

Even though I would assume that it would work, i've got 404 errors :

[image]

In order to make it work, I have to add the folder name prefix like so :

```
<script src="mood/js/angular.js"></script>
```

Which is not what I want because when I'll push my work into the Git repo, other users wont have the "mood" folder.

How should I proceed to make it work without folder name prefix?

Thanks guys.

Comment: How do you serve the files? Is there is any config for server to share?

Comment: There must be a problem with your local server. It serves files from your projects folder.

Comment: I'm using basic WAMP configuration. The weird part is that it works fine for css folder (there is no 404 error with css folder), but it starts struggling with the JS file and I believe this is because of Angular behaviour as I request the ng-app directive BEFORE adding angular script.

Comment: can you please expose your entire HTML?

Comment: As index.html is in root folder , it should work like script src="js/angular.js"></script>

Comment: Here you go : http://pastebin.com/tAyaEFnZ

Comment: @GreatHawkeye check the answer . I hope it will resolve the `404` issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [HTML base tag](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_base.asp) **:**

```
<head>
<base href="http://localhost/mood/"> or <base href="/">
</head>

<body ng-app="Mood">

<div id="moodApp" ng-view></div>

<script src="js/angular.js"></script>
<script src="js/angular-route-min.js"></script>
<script src="js/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.2.1/Chart.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/main.js"></script>
```

The **`<base>`** tag specifies the base **`URL/target`** for all relative URLs in a document.

**Note :** If the  tag is present, it must have either an href attribute or a target attribute, or both.

Comment: @GreatHawkeye mark it as correct so that it will be useful for others also.

Answer (score 0):

Using relative path you can do this

use ../js/(remainnig path according to file in js folder).

Comment: I do have the exact same 404 error with the same files location. I am assuming the issue come from Angular behaviour as the body tag is using angular at the opening tag even though I did not linked the script yet...

Comment: did you try above solution  ? if its not working than what path it will try to take ?   check in console and mention it.

Comment: Yes I did try it and I have the exact same error as the very first screenshot I took " http://localhost/js/angular.js  "

Comment: did you try ./js/--- path , actually your index file is in the root directory so , try using one (.) .